# Где и как мне скачать и установить плагин на MSVS 10?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно вот такое:

```
using DirectShowLib;
```

Не могу разобраться какая библиотека нужна для этого, где её найти и как установить.

Прошу у Вас помощи, Уважаемые.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Download DirectShowLibV2-1.zip (345.6 kB)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/)

Comment: Так, окей, скачал... а как установить-то, что бы работаело?

Comment: Ну распаковываешь архив. В нем как правило должны быть релизные dll'ки. Заходишь в настройки своего проекта, выбираешь Add References, дальше Browse, выбираешь путь к dll'ке на жестком диске, клацаешь ок, пишешь using в своей программе, вуаля!